# What difference between Mann-whintey U-test and Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on truncated log normal distributions?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, methodology, ab-test, two-sample

I have two populations who have been exposed to two different websites that should bring them to donations: one with a progress bar that pushes them to give (B, segment 2) and the other not (A, segment 1).

[image]

And with log(y):

[image]

So it looks log-normal.

I have noticed that, on average, population B gives much more than A:

```
                 s1          s2
count   3352.000000 3053.000000
mean    86.137828   109.417294
std     239.235495  231.897494
min     2.000000    3.000000
25%     20.000000   25.000000
50%     30.000000   50.000000
75%     60.000000   100.000000
max     9000.000000 6200.000000
```

I know that, as my distributions aren't normally distributed I need to have a non-parametric test **but I wanted to know what method should I use to test that. Should I use a U-test or a Ks-test?** Because I tried both and they gave different results.

Indeed the U-test ([scipy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html)) gave:

```
p = stats.mannwhitneyu(np.log(df_segment_1), np.log(df_segment_2), use_continuity=True, alternative='less')

alpha = 0.05
if p[1] > alpha:
    print('Same distribution (fail to reject H0)')
else:
  print("p : ", p[1])
  print('Different distribution (reject H0)')
```

```
p :  6.975597756441267e-11
Different distribution (reject H0)
```

Whereas the ks test ([scipy library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html)) rejects the null hypothesis:

```
p = stats.ks_2samp(np.log(df_segment_1), np.log(df_segment_2), alternative='less')

alpha = 0.05
if p[1] > alpha:
  print("p : ", p[1])
  print('Same distribution (fail to reject H0)')
else:
  print("p : ", p[1])
  print('Different distribution (reject H0)')
```

```
p :  0.9954748308681242
Same distribution (fail to reject H0)
```

These results are very-different. Did I did a mistake? Or is one of them not fit for the use?

Comment: KS is sensitive to many differences besides differences in mean. Wilcoxon can be sensitive to such differences, too, but it is harder to "trick" that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the documentation of stats.ks_2samp correctly, alternative="less" means that the cdf of data A is smaller that the one of data B. This means that the distribution with cdf A tends to produce *larger* values. alternative="less" for Mann-Whitney means that the distribution of A tends to produce *smaller* values. The $H_0$ is rejected significantly in favour of this alternative; data A looks like produced by a distribution that is "stochastically smaller". The same direction of test would somewhat counter-intuitively require "alternative="greater"" in stats.ks_2samp.

If you're interested in testing whether the distributions are significantly different (without pre-specifying the direction), try alternative="two-sided" for both.

PS: Note that the Mann-Whitney test was specifically constructed to test whether one distribution is stochastically smaller or larger than the other. The KS-test is suitable for detecting *any* kind of difference between them. Meaning that if you are interested whether they differ in a general sense, KS should be preferable, but for testing whether one is stochastically larger or smaller than the other, I'd prefer Mann-Whitney.

PS2: Note that generally it invalidates tests if you choose what to test based on having seen the data. If *before seeing the data* you didn't have any particular suspicion which sample would produce larger values, only a two-sided test can be valid. If before seeing the data it was of special interest to you whether sample B would tend to give you larger values, you can justify a one-sided test (alternative="less", "greater", respectively).

Answer (score 2):

Without being an expert on scipy, it looks as if you're specifying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov to test whether or not the $s_1$ CDF is "smaller" than the $s_2$ CDF. So your $p$ is the probability of a difference in distributions and *not* the $p$ of your $H_0$.

Comment: Oh; ok! So should the $p$ of $H_0 $ be $1-p$ obtained? Why is it different with the U-test?

Comment: Specify "two-sided" instead of "less" as the option :-)